# Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp in Mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, select

I'm having trouble using a regular expression to select some results from my MySQL table.

I'm using this query

```
select id, orderid, `desc`
from paymentlog
where `desc` REGEXP '[^.]*(?:_SVD(\d*))[[:>:]]'
```

And it says

> `#1139` - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

This regex works well with my other editors/validators.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: `(?:)` doesn't make much sense for mysql

Comment: Also, `\d` doesn't mean what you think!

Answer (score 6):

[MySQL regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) don't support the full syntax of [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

The `(?:)` grouping syntax is not supported in MySQL. That syntax is for grouping without backreferences. But it doesn't matter in MySQL, since MySQL doesn't support backreferences anyway (related to this, MySQL has no regular expression substitution function).

In fact, you don't need any parens in your example.

As @ruakh says, `\d` isn't a code to match digits. You need to use POSIX character classes in MySQL.

So your expression should look like this:

```
where `desc` REGEXP '_SVD[:digit:]*[[:>:]]'
```

I also left out your `[^.]*` since it doesn't matter in this expression. You aren't matching the beginning of the string, so *zero* characters of that class would succeed the match even if you did have a `.` before the rest of the pattern. You might mean to match only if you have non-dot characters from the start of the string, like this:

```
where `desc` REGEXP '^[^.]*_SVD[:digit:]*[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: This expression doesn't throw error, however it does not match my string "My Style 002_SVD1455466". Particularly the end of word does not work.

Comment: Finally the expression is ^[^%]*_SVD[0-9]+$ to match my strings